# PL/SQL take input as table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE 
 tablename table;
 nor number(10);
BEGIN 
    tablename:=&tablename;
    select count(*) into nor from tablename;
    dbms_output.put_line('The number of rows are '||nor);
END;
/
```

I am using this code to take table name as input from user and displaying the row count but it shows errors but if use a specific table name it runs fine!

Comment: You need create a string quey and use `EXECUTE`,  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm

Comment: Simply put you can't do it this way.  You have to use dynamic SQL.  Construct the SQL statement as a string ad execute it as @JuanCarlosOropeza points out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE 
 tablename table;
 nor number(10);
BEGIN 
    tablename:=&tablename;
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from '|| tablename
      into nor;
    dbms_output.put_line('The number of rows are '||nor);
END;
/
```

You can try to use EXECUTE IMMDEDIATE

Comment: tablename has type "table" not a varchar2?